# Should a Down Vote require a comment?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, voting

Would it be a reasonable to require Down Votes on questions (and maybe answers) force the user to first leave a comment, or mark an attached comment as great?

This would be to help prevent blind down votes. It seems to me that down votes without feed back do not really do the original poster (or the site) any good, other than letting everyone know that someone dislikes the question for some random reason.

Comment: I agree, and [even had my own stab at this over on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66020/different-implementation-of-downvoting-require-comments).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This [dead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/31302/172958) [horse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97484/172958) [has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/29531/172958) [been](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30255/172958) [beaten](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55380/172958) [on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6521/172958) [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) for years. The answer is no.

Comment: Lots of meat on that dead horse. Have to remember that MSO is there...

Comment: Okay, lots of links -- which one is best for a summary if we don't want to read a novel?

Comment: @TangoOversway [This one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6521/177670) and [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135/177670) I felt covered it best.

Comment: Should overuse of dead horse expression require a downvote?

Comment: @Xantec: thanks -- that was easier than reading screens and screens full of arguments! ;)

Comment: @TangoOversway GraceNote's answer to Wikis' question is also good.

Answer (score -3):

If the concept of the "down vote" (that it seems to be according to this [link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)) is to improve the site then I agree with Xantec that it should require some justification that would allow the person asking the question to learn how to improve.

According to an answer from this [question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13705/removal-of-down-votes-from-reopened-questions/13707?noredirect=1#comment48197_13707), down votes can be for any reason whatsoever. Nothing at all about improving the site for users.

So, I  don't particularly like stuff about Manga. Would this make it OK for all people not to like Manga to down vote them, ensuring these questions go to another site? Of course not.

Comment: "*Would this make it OK for all people not to like Manga to down vote them*" - Yes, absolutely you can downvote question-types that you don't like.

Comment: @Valorum and how, exactly, does that promote the encouragement of good questions?

Comment: Because the site is its users and if its users don't like a particular class of question, then discouraging their asking is going to improve the site

Answer (score -5):

Of coarse it would be a good idea to require a user to comment as to why they leave a down vote.

Constructive criticism is the base of improvement, without it we are all just flailing about with no direction.

Comment: The problem is that some people aren't looking for an explanation of why they're getting downvoted, they're looking for someone to blame.