# Are comments on-topic if they are referring to downvotes and other questions?

Tags: discussion, flagging, comments

I flagged the comment trail [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60522/did-ivanova-and-talia-have-a-romantic-relationship-in-babylon-5) as off-topic, but my flag was declined.  I'm confused as to how downvotes and Captain Kirk are on-topic to a question about two Babylon 5 characters.

Why was my flag declined?

Comment: The comment ontopicness on this site is a lot more relaxed than on some other SE sites. Frankly, i find that it improves the site tremendously.

Comment: @DVK Which is fine, I just want to make sure my flags match the site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think comments about downvotes are on-topic, because they’re supposed to help the asker improve their question (in the eyes of the downvoter).

We often have comments that lament the *lack of* a comment from the downvoter, but there’s not much to be done about that. The question of whether [downvotes should require a comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1395/3567) has been discussed ad nauseam (the answer is no), but those comments are still on-topic, because they still seek to improve the question and/or understand why others didn’t like it.

Same applies for comments about downvotes on answers.

I don’t know anything about Babylon 5 or Star Trek, so I can neither follow nor comment upon the particular comment thread you linked to.

Comment: Asking why something was downvoted doesn't rub me the wrong way.  It's the comments saying "Another downvote? Really?  Ok, I'll upvote to offset" that I think don't really add anything to the question or the finding out why anyone is downvoting.

Comment: @DavidWilkins - I've posted comments like that before, but they would also include "it's actually a good question because of reasons A, B, C".  The point is that challenging the downvote and providing reasons for that challenge make this kind of comment valid.

Comment: @JimmyShelter Kinda like mine did, with the comparison to Kirk.  [This is the question I was comparing it to](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36652/did-captain-kirk-take-advantage-of-drusilla); Drusilla is a one-off character that only appears in that episode

Comment: Well I am really glad I posted this here, I should be able to more accurately flag in the future.  Thanks guys! :-)